# Run Two Functions (One In External File, One In Inline Javascript) On window.onload

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm developing a website and I have an external JavaScript file that is linked to every page of the site which executes when the `window.onload` event is fired. The JavaScript executes fine on all pages which do not contain any inline JavaScript.

Any page that contains inline JavaScript also contains a JavaScript function which executes when the `window.onload` event is fired.

The problem I'm having is that the external JavaScript does not execute when `window.onload` is fired, only the internal JavaScript does. It appears as if the inline JavaScript function overwrites the function from the external JavaScript file.

I know that my external JavaScript file is first executed and then the inline JavaScript is executed. Is there anyway that I can execute both functions on `window.onload`?

Comment: Are you using the syntax `window.onload = function () { }` of some sort?

Comment: You cannot assign more than one function to `window.onload`. If you have multiple handlers for the same event, you need to resort to dedicated event API. I recommend a library that contains such API (e.g. jQuery).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about changing the script that executes second to something like this:

```
var onload = function () {
    // Do something
    alert('Hello');
};

if(window.onload) {
    // If a function is already bound to the onload event, execute that too.
    var fn = window.onload;
    window.onload = function () {
        fn();
        onload();
    };
} else {
    window.onload = onload;
}
```

Or use a library like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) which lets you do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('Hello');
}
```

Comment: Thanks @fsmmu ...By Rewriting The Inline JavaScript as a jQuery function both now execute when the page loads! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

This might be more of a work around than a proper fix but could you put your inline JS at the bottom of the html page so it is automatically called after the page is loaded. That will mean you don't have to actually use `window.onload()`

Comment: The "load" event is fired after all the resources of the page have been loaded (images, etc.). A script at the bottom might execute before that. There are no guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways :

1 - Use addEventListener.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){ /*code*/ }, false);
```

2 - Use a hack like this:

```
var func = window.onload;
window.onload = function() {
    if ( func ) func();
    /* code */
};
```

Comment: `addEventListener()` is not implemented in IE8 - this cannot be ignored.